# How do we get underlying geometry of a Path in Paper.js?

Tags: paperjs

We can draw a rectangle in many ways and one of them is first defining a `Rectangle` and then draw it with `Path.Rectangle`:

```
var rect = new Rectangle({
    from: [80, 50],
    to: [100, 200]
})

var rpath = new Path.Rectangle(rect)
rpath.strokeColor = 'red'
```

After this point, if we loose `rect` (if we don't keep the pointer or we export/import the project), we can not know `rpath` is a `Rectangle` or not.

How can we decide if a `Path` is `Circle` or `Rectangle` or `Polygon` or `Polyline`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Path.Rectangle`, `Path.Circle` etc... are simply [factory functions that return a `Path`](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/1335#issuecomment-306790258), which simply *looks* like a rectangle. They are not subclasses/types.

So no, there's no straightforward way to infer the type.

As a workaround, you  can store a `type` prop in `item.data`, which survives serialisation/reimporting.

```
var rect = new Rectangle({
    from: [80, 50],
    to: [100, 200]
})

var rpath = new Path.Rectangle(rect)
rpath.strokeColor = 'red'
rpath.data = { type: 'rectangle' }

var serialized = rpath.exportJSON()
var reimported = paper.project.importJSON(serialized)

console.log(reimported.data.type)
```

And here's the [Sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/RZBPa4QwEMW/SshFBQnZQqEIPfXWQ7t0j6uHVKe71pgJY+g/8bt3El3MafLm5TdvMktnRpCVPA0Q2qssZYtdvH8ZEgRtEI/Cwbd449K4i4V8rp3g80E4VuL8oEtxr5tyFQOydNCs3Wnd1G4pale7hPImXDfWkUu1A+MU9iWHmgLhAE9okdidEXTZrdWZYFibRfj1UMXeRsjEchszAfXG9n/QsXN9Bj8eKTyfXl/yYssC/Ri1ZPLGAylP+Mk4tTaSeUelJVp0E1pQFi/5DkihVAxU8Ne9E5jBY+/CJKtzs/wD).

There are other solutions you can try:

- Subclass `Path` to your own `Rectangle` type. Subclassing is not officially supported but still doable, through `paper.Path.extend()`.
- Add a method `Path.isRectangle()` which inspects the segments and mathematically determines if it's a rectangle or not, at runtime.